# Create installer for weblogic

Tags: java, bash, jar, installation, weblogic

Is it possible to create installer for WebLogic server with bash scripts that no need to follow weblogic Installation guide with this permission that Befor start install weblogic make sure that its requirement were installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you *can* create an install script that accepts a set of input parameters and installs via command line.

No, you *shouldn't*, because you're reinventing the wheel, probably badly. Use an off-the-shelf provisioner like ansible, chef or puppet - there are [plugins available](https://forge.puppet.com/biemond/wls) that will install weblogic for you.

Or use a Docker image that has WLS on it or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it! 
Why dont u use the shipped installer in silent mode with all the parameters you need?
Or you can create a WebLogic template(tar/jar/dockercontainer/whatever) and roll this out...